# How to make my chat-bot accessible from a web page?

Tags: botframework, chatbot

I've got my Node.JS bot builder chatbot all working in the emulator, but I'm not sure how I can get started in allowing my bot to be chatted to by others through the internet, on a web page.

I've seen [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-quickstart-registration) article, but this seems to be if we want to host the both through Azure. Additionally, I'm not sure how I'd link the code I made for the bot with this.

This is for a school project for a local company, so I'm fairly sure (and will ask) that they want this to be free to run on their own servers, instead of paying Microsoft.

Can anyone help me understand how this all works?

Comment: "This is for a school project for a local company": maybe you have a free Azure subscription with your school? By the way, hosting a simple bot in Azure can be free

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MS Botframework & LUIS, you will have to host your webhook somewhere to make it accessible to public. Now, if you do not want to spend a penny for hosting services, I'd like to suggest you one more bot platform dialogflow.com (api.ai) where they have built-in inline editor (Powered by Cloud Functions for Firebase). You will just have to write your code there & say deploy. You won't be charged unless you're using a standard edition.

Now, second thing, if you do not want to do any of these & still want to make it public, you will have to have your own servers & all & expose your IP. Put that computer in the DMZ of your router. That is what it is for. Or, simply forward the needed ports. But here you will have to manage everything on your own like if a server goes down etc. Hope this helps.